# When I customize HTML form elements (ie. drop down lists, radio buttons, etc), what are some performance considerations to keep in mind?

Tags: html, css, forms

Looking for help on the HTML/CSS side of things.  Obviously light, lean code is ideal...But does the styling of these elements really matter for a small web-app?

Generally speaking, are there any HTML form elements you wouldn't touch because of the hit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a loading perspective, you'll be fine with just adding some css. It shouldn't be very noticeable.

That said, you can get in trouble quickly by trying to style input elements to look a specific way. Honestly it depends what your trying to accomplish. For example putting a border around a radio button is close to impossible. Also making custom select boxes can be difficult pending the design. Styling these elements can get time consuming to make sure they work cross browser. I'd recommend keeping them standard whenever possible to ensure your site looks good across the board and saves you development time.

Comment: Thanks, AJak! I definitely think the "beauty" aspect of the designs I'm trying to create is probably too high to be practical for a cross-browser solution.  Back to the drawing board...

Answer (score 0):

CSS loads very fast, and is very light compared to pretty much everything else you can do to a web page, so I wouldn't be worried about it. This answer assumes that you didn't mean styling with images.

Comment: I would agree with this statement. I would also recommend reducing the amount of selectors. For example, don't use `.my_class #my_id {do something}` when just `#my_id {do something}` will work. Although the effects are essentially unnoticeable.

Comment: Thank you...One quick follow up about drop shadows...Are they inherently page killers?  I see so many apps rely on the shadows for depth that I can imagine it makes a big deal.

Comment: @jawise Drop shadows are a great way to make elements on your page "pop" but only when done right. The biggest hurdle when it comes to drop shadows, and all "advanced" CSS styling is cross-browser compatibility. Really, from a performance standpoint, CSS is as lightweight as they come. It's all of the small nuances that are needed to ensure your page looks just as good in Chrome as it does in IE that are difficult to nail down.

Answer (score 0):

There is really no need to worry about speed when sticking to pure html and css. I feel like the trend with javascript webapps is to reduce the amount of html tags used to a minimum and do a lot of javascript programming. In a nutshell when you write html code try not to use obscure tags for the sake of readability but as for loading time they are all just text and generally load very fast

Answer (score 0):

Keep accessibility in mind as well: some folks have a hard time with some color combinations, and some folks need to bump up the size of text to make it readable. Your controls should deal with both issues.